# When applying for an EB-2 NIW green card as a French citizen, can I somewhere in the process ask the USCIS to only use my 1st first name (+last name)?

Tags: usa, france, greencard, names

[French citizens may have more than one first name](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F882). When applying for an EB-2 NIW green card as a French citizen, can I somewhere in the process ask the USCIS to only use my first first name (+ my last name), and drop my other first names, so that the green card (and subsequent US official documents) only contains the first first name?

Comment: The best way to do this might be to get a legal name change document from a court, or however it is handled in your state of residence.  But do you really want a discrepancy between your US and French documents?  Regardless, there's going to be confusion, because most Americans would assume that your subsequent given name (or names) should be "middle" names.

Comment: @phoog  [What problems can having 2 passports with 2 different first names cause?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24317/164)

Answer (score 0):

No, USCIS will identify you by your full name. If you want to change the name, you'll need to go through a judge (at least in the US, may be different rules in France).

Comment: It seems that they won't use the _entire_ name if the given names exceed 18 characters in length, in which case they will use only the first 18 characters.

Comment: Where does it seem that way? It may be a purely technical limitation, not that your name is officially changed.

Comment: It's absolutely a purely technical limitation.  I say "it seems" because I found the 18-character limit by searching online.  I have not investigated the reliability of the sources.  The machine readable zone of the green card has 30 positions for the full name, but that doesn't have much bearing on the character limit in the "given name" field of the "visual inspection zone."